# API gateway returning corrupted excel file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My API end point returns an excel file streamed from S3. It works on the local but when testing on API gateway the file is corrupted. Here is my API code:

```
const downloadContentFromS3 = async function(bucket, file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    streamFileFromS3(bucket, file, (error, s3buffer) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      return resolve(s3buffer);
    });
  });
};

const streamFileFromS3 = async function(bucket, fileName, callback) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: fileName,
  };

  const buffers = [];
  const stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
  stream.on('data', data => buffers.push(data));
  stream.on('end', () => callback(null, Buffer.concat(buffers)));
  stream.on('error', error => callback(error));
};

downloadExcelFile: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const fileName = 'myFilename';
    const workbook = await downloadContentFromS3(
      'bucket-name'        
      fileName
    );
    const workbook = xlsx.read(buffer);

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}`);
    res.setHeader(
      'Content-type',
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    );
    const wbout = xlsx.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
    res.status(200).send(Buffer.from(wbout));
  } catch (error) {
    throw new OriolaError(error.message);
  }
},
```

**What I have tried so far:**  Setup the binary media types as shown in the picture:[image]

In addition tried to set the **RESPONSE HEADER** to Content-Type and Content-Disposition but to no avail. The problem seems to persist. Any ideas and help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have also tried to set binary type `*/*` in the settings but this does not help as well.

Comment: What about base64? Maybe its getting downloaded in base64 encoding?

Comment: How can I make it correct then ? Provide the options for the header which can achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

API Gateway and Lambda send files between themselves as base64. This is regardless of whether you set a binary media type on API Gateway, as API Gateway does the conversion between base64 and binary.

S3 getObject gets a binary file, but that is a moot point for your problem, as you are still creating a binary file with xlsx.

What you are currently doing is sending binary data untransformed as base64 data.

All you need to do is return the file as a base64 buffer instead of a binary one.

So

```
res.status(200).send(Buffer.from(wbout));
```

becomes

```
res.status(200).send(Buffer.from(wbout).toString('base64'));
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

So either

- setup `passthrough behaviour` and send binary response body from your function as you are already doing,
- or set the `contentHandling` property of the `IntegrationResponse resource` to `CONVERT_TO_BINARY` in addition to `binaryMediaTypes` setting already done and then send `base64` response body.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I have passthrough enabled, I'm sending the buffer and it still gets corrupted

Comment: @luca.p.alexandru were you able to figure out what was causing the error??

Comment: @Himanshu yes, but I can't remember how I fixed it

Comment: could you send me the API gateway config in case you have it handy??, I have been stuck on this for the last 3 days would really appreciate any help